# Bucardo replication from slave to master

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, bucardo

Some context first;

I'm currently dealing with an event that my company is attending and we want to have people sign up from our live, production environment and have our event kit pull new signups from that as such that they'll be recognised by kit we're running locally at the event.

Now, because of the ad-hoc nature it makes sense to have the replication agent on the slave and call out (via a VPN) to our production server.

I've set up Bucardo on our event kit, configured the master as the remote machine and the slave on the local machine.

Doing my first sync seems just to last forever, using Bucardo to ping the process times out, so I assume nothing's running.

Is it even possible to run this way round? Or does the master always have to be the local system?

Help/advice appreciated.

Cheers,

Dave.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong .... but I don't think you can replicate from slave (without making it as master also), it has to be from master.

One alternative might be to just use plain \copy via a job scheduler.